# Implementing interactive popover / callouts in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're doing a project in Angular.js and the Mockups we're getting from our UX person heavily use interactive popovers / callouts.

[image: ui popover - dialog example]

The problem is that I can't seem to map these on to angular concepts in a clean way.  Conceptually they require their own templates, controllers, and they need to be created and destroyed all over the page.  Overlapping elements without changing the layout.

Bootstrap modals aren't seen as an acceptable alternative.  The founders are really keen on having interactive dialogs that point at specific elements on the page.

Is there something that can accomplish this?  Or do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a directive or set of directives that you can show on focus or blur or mouseover of other elements. Depending on your implementation, you might be able to get away with just one directive that opens onFocus or onBLur. Angular 1.2 supports ng-focus, ng-mouseover, and ng-blur which you can leverage to do something like this.

```
<div class="check-thing">
   <button class="checkmark" ng-mouseenter="showModal = true" ng-mouseleave="showModal = false"></button>
   <modal ng-show="showModal" model="modal-model"></modal>
</div>
```

Then just have the form in the directive populate a two-way bound modal-model, or fire a callback when the user clicks okay that the controller waits for. It might even be better to just make the whole checker thing a directive and use them in a repeat.

**Beware**, none of this will be very friendly on a tablet or phone as they don't readily support hovers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the AngularUI Bootstrap modals? (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) They fit very well into AngularJS and can really be styled into almost any appearance you want. Passing data in and getting data out is very easy. Most UX people don't seem to understand how the web works (mine doesn't seem to anyway) and these have been a real savior for me and my team.

Comment: He said in his question that they aren't acceptable solutions, though I am not sure why as they are perfectly legit and style-able angular options.

Comment: I'm actually using those now.  The founders really want absolutely positioned elements that point to specific elements.

Comment: He said BOOTSTRAP modals, which I interpreted to be plain old Bootstrap and not AngularUI Bootstrap.

wmil - You just need to override the CSS and you can position/style those modals to appear however you want. I have one positioned at the bottom right that acts as a menu when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but since an answer was never selected I would like to point out a possible solution that I had come across recently.

The Angular UI BS Popover allows you to have it align with the element you are targeting, which can be click, hoover, and focus.

For content you have the choice between text, HTML formatted string and template.  Based on the question, the template is likely the one that would be used to allow the content to be dynamic and include interaction.

You can find more information and a demo on how it works at: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/